# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable cuando hago scraping en YouTube usando Python

Tags: python, scraping, youtube

Estoy tratando de crear un YouTube scraper (obtener los comentarios de un video de YouTube) pero recibí un error cuando hacía el bucle.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-13-93cdd7da1663> in <module>()
     10     response=youtube.video_comments()
     11 
---> 12     for c in response['body']:
     13         data.append(c)
     14 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Este es mi código.

```
data = []
currentpagesource=youtube.get_page_source()
lastpagesource=''

while(True):
    if(lastpagesource==currentpagesource):
        break
        
    lastpagesource=currentpagesource
    response=youtube.video_comments()

    for c in response['body']:
        data.append(c)
        
    youtube.scroll()
    currentpagesource=youtube.get_page_source()
```

Como pueden observar, estoy tratando de utilizar Selenium en Google Colab. ¿Qué puedo hacer para resolver este problema?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Estás en Stack Overflow en español. Podrías traducir tu pregunta o eliminarla y preguntar en el sitio en inglés por favor?

Comment: Muchas gracias por señalarlo, la voy a traducir.

Comment: De nada! Pero pensando en tu pregunta, no se que modulo usas (me lo podrías decir por favor?). Lo unico que logro notar es que por alguna razón, el comando youtube.video_comments() devuelve None. Luego intentas acceder a una clave del supuesto diccionario. Pero es la nada misma, no un diccionario.

Comment: `response` es `None`. El por qué no sé, eso  depende de tu código, pero puedes evitarlo con un `if response:`